# Доступ CSS к родительскому элементу

Tags: css, jquery

Всем привет есть такой html

```
<label class="quad">
   <input class="quadcheck" name="1" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="">11
</label>

<label class="quad">
   <input class="quadcheck" name="2" type="checkbox" value="1">22
</label>
```

Один checkbox - checked, Другой нет. Как сделать так, что бы стили label были определенные у checked чекбокса?
Через jquery делал вот так

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('.quadcheck').is(":checked"))
    {
        $('.quadcheck').parent().css("background-color", "#fcfc00");    
    }
});
```

Но он к обоим почему то дает стили

Comment: через CSS никак. в JS такие селекторы `:has()` работают, а в CSS нет. https://hcdev.ru/css/has/

Comment: Чтобы стили label напрямую зависели от состояния чекбокса, проще всего поставить label следом за чекбоксом и использовать соседний селектор +

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы проверяете есть ли checked, а потом берете не его, а все инпуты, и перекрашиваете. Тут не нужно условие, просто сразу берите checked input

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('input:checked').parent().css("background-color", "#fcfc00");    
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="quad">
   <input class="quadcheck" name="1" type="checkbox" value="1" checked="">11
</label>

<label class="quad">
   <input class="quadcheck" name="2" type="checkbox" value="1">22
</label>
```

Ну и плюс я полагаю надо не только раз его вызывать, но и на клик еще его привязать.